# Recordar campos de un formulario en el navegador no funciona con llamadas ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Al crear un formulario de la forma normal es decir:

```
<form action="index.html" method="post">
</form>
```

Al enviar o hacer submit de los datos de cada input estos se guardan(los recuerda el navegador) y se muestran en los input la siguiente vez que se teclea algo parecido. Por ejemplo:

[image: Form]

Sin embargo al hacerlo mediante ajax no se guardan los valores.

La llamada ajax que tengo es la siguiente:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                    'id_documento_interno': id_documento_interno,
                    'nro_documento': nro_documento,
                    'tipo_documento': tipo_documento,
                    'codigo_documento': codigo_documento,
                    'peticionario_documento': peticionario_documento,
                    'jefatura_documento': jefatura_documento,
                    'asunto_documento': asunto_documento,
                    'hojas_documento': hojas_documento,
                    'fecha_documento': fecha_documento,
                    'observacion_documento': observacion_documento
                  },
            url: "<?php echo base_url();?>"+"general/documento/actualizarInternoPorId",
            success : function(data) {
              if (data == '1') {
                swal({
                      title: 'Correcto!',
                      text: 'Tramite Ingresado Correctamente! Para enviarlo vaya a la seccion enviar.',
                      type: 'success',
                      showCancelButton: true,
                      confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
                      cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
                      confirmButtonText: 'Continuar',
                      cancelButtonText: 'Cancelar'
                    }).then(function () {
                      $('#addinterno').modal('close');
                      $("#agregarinterno")[0].reset();
                      console.log("Generado");
                      window.location.href = "generados";
                    });

              }else {
                swal(
                      'Error!',
                      'Ha ocurrido un error generando trámite, contacte al administrador!',
                      'error'
                    )
              }
            }
        });
```

Mi pregunta es: **¿Cómo se podría hacer funcionar el autocompletado de los inputs cuando se envian valores a través de ajax?**

Comment: Es una muy buena pregunta! Si en el `submit` del `form` haces `return false;` o si haces `evt.preventDefault();` no se guardan. El tema es que si no lo haces, el `form` se envía...

Comment: Tienes razón, aunque en este caso solo estoy enviando los datos por ajax, usando la funcion on() de jquery, `$('#boton').on('click',function(){//llamada ajax});` no hago uso de submit

Comment: Te dejo el enlace a [una solución alternativa](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15462991/trigger-autocomplete-without-submitting-a-form) mientras indago mas sobre el tema.

Comment: Gracias @MarcosGallardo ahora reviso el enlace, :)

Answer (score 1):

*No sé si ya has resuelto esto, pero te comparto mi idea.*

Desgraciadamente no pueden enviarse "señales" al navegador para que resuelva cierta intención de una página (p.ej. *"guarda los datos en el formulario en tu caché de autocompletado"*); además de que sería algo difícil de implementar dada la infinidad de navegadores existentes; por lo tanto dicho comportamiento se basa en estándares: el html tiene un estándar formal para envío de formularios... y en dicho estándar no está involucrado el uso de javascript (ajax).

Mi recomendación (*no tan elegante*) sería recurrir a dichos comportamientos: en el momento en que tu código ajax tiene éxito con la operación de guardado, en vez de redireccionar (usando `window.location.target`), requerir un submit html del formulario, cambiando la acción hacia una página *fake* cuya única función sea la de redireccionar a tu nueva ubicación. El resultado será que el navegador guarde los valores en su caché, aunque la operación real sea realizada mediante ajax.

En código sería algo así:

---

#### HTML:

La parte importante es el atributo `action` del formulario: una página cuya función sea redirigir al cliente a una nueva URL, especificada en el mismo parámetro.

```
<form id="forma" action="redirect.php?url=generados" method="post">
  <div>
    <label for="numeroSerie">Numero de serie:</label>
    <input id="numeroSerie"/>
  </div>
  <!-- etc. -->
  <div>
    <button id="guardar">Guardar</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

---

#### Javascript:

La diferencia de este código es el reemplazo de la redirección mediante `window.location` al uso del submit html.

```
$('#guardar').on('click', function(event) {
  // evitar que se lance el submit por defecto
  event.preventDefault();

  // intentar operación ajax
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    datatype: 'JSON',
    data: {
      // datos del formulario a enviar
    },
    url: 'url_que_guarda_el_formulario.php',
    success: function(data) {
      if (data == 1) {
        swal({
          // configuración del swal: éxito
        }).then(function() {
          // reiniciar estado

          // ... y después lanzar submit del formulario html
          $('#forma').submit();
        });
      }
      else {
        swal({
          // configuración del swal: error
        });
      }
    }
  });
});
```

---

Y para la redirección en php (lo que corresponde a `redirect.php` en el ejemplo) se puede hacer lo que se [sugiere aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/768472/1732224).